# Use currently logged in user in Dynamics CRM 2015 configured with IFD, to authenticate against an external MVC application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication, dynamics-crm-2015, adfs3.0

I have a Dynamics CRM 2015 on premise instance, IFD configured with claims authentication, as recommended from Microsoft, and working OK.

There is also a separate angular application, wrapped in, in ASP.NET MVC web application. The angular part i assume is not related much, but nevertheless, let it be here for complete picture.
I also have it configured to work with ADFS claims authentication, with the point being, the user to be logged in, and using the application, in the same user context in both CRM and web app. So when a user is using the application, he is using it with the user he logged in, in CRM with.

So, when i try to access the app URL, i get redirected to the adfs login, from which after logging in, i get redirected to my app index page. This is working fine as well.

In CRM i have a ribbon button which transfers selected records, to the web app, directly to the web app url, so as *https://webapp.domain.com:port*. Selected records is mentioned here only as info, and it is not related to the problem.

Now, my problem is, when i access CRM, i login to ADFS, and then try to click the button to open web app URL, i get the ADFS login screen again. If i try to login with the same user, i am stuck in a loop without any requests being sent, and the fields are constantly clearing, without the possibility of logging in. 
So the users cannot access it anymore. It is not browser related.

***Correction:***

*Requests are getting sent, and the login request appears in the audit log in event viewer, as successful, but the redirection doesn't seem to happen. Also, it seems to be browser related, not sure how I've missed it before:*

- *IE:* *I get a windows login instead of ADFS login, and after inputting password, i get redirected, and then logged in OK. This login should not show though.*
- *Chrome:* *Constant loop, and a console issue logged: The specified value "DOMAIN\USERNAME" is not a valid email address.*
- *Firefox: Fields, are constantly cleared in a loop.*

***End Correction***

If i clear the cache, or firstly login to the web app directly, then there is no problem, and opening the URL from CRM after that works normally.

This issue is turning out to be quite of a drag, as i do not know how to address it. Has anyone had similar issue, with external apps logging in with claims, to let me know what i am missing?

Claims rules for the web app are below:
[image: Claims rules for MVC app]

Comment: Are there any errors being logged in the AD FS Event Log when the failure occurs?

Comment: Hi Neil, thank you for the comment, sorry for a bit late response. I haven't checked for adfs logs, as there are no requests sent. What i am thinking is, there must be something wrong with the cookies locally, as when the issue happens, there are no requests sent back to the server, like something gets messed up with the redirection. I will check the logs and update.

Comment: Corrected one issue in the question, requests are getting sent, and the request shows in the audit log in event viewer, as successful.